# Kernel of linear mapping from infinitely differentiable function to their derivatives

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, linear-transformations

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Let $V$ be the vector space of functions which have derivatives of all
>   orders, and let $D:V \rightarrow V$ be the derivative. What is the kernel of $D$?

This seems to be a very simple question, with very simple answer that I've constructed, though I'm not aware of how sufficient would it be.

---

I'm assuming, that "vector space of functions which have derivatives of all orders" is basically a function space of infinitely differentiable functions over some arbitrary field $K$ ([since function space over a field $K$ is a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2883498/513294)).

From basic calculus, we are aware of [Fermat's interior extremum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)), and that every point that has derivative of $0$ (stationary point) is local extremum (either maxima, minima or a saddle point).

Hence, the kernel of infinitely differentiable functions under $D$ is a space spanned by all local extremum's of infinitely differentiable functions.

Is this highly simple answer sufficient? or should I add something more.

Thank you!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks, it was supposed to say "a function in the kernel has the _zero function_ as _derivative_", of course. I was trying to make a different point, but that incorrect formulation certainly didn't help... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that it is implicit here that $V$ is the space of all fonctions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ which have derivatives of all orders. Then$$\ker D=\left\{f\in V\,\middle|\,f'=0\right\}.$$But the functions $f$ such that $f'$ is the null function are the constant functions and only those functions.

Comment: Oh, I should've utilized the definition of kernel more appropriately... Hence every point of the function's derivative is stationary, not just some specific one. Thank you!